# Edit UItextview from UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitextview

I have a UIbutton and I would like when I press it to edit the content of a UITextView with the Keyboard.
I have been looking a lot on internet and finally found nothing of documentation about to programaticaly edit an UITextView.

It is possible to do this ?

Comment: The button action method should just make the textView the firstResponder. That will cause the keyboard to appear. You may want to do this as a dispatch block to the main queue so the button unhighlites first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UITextView` natively supports editing.  Try this:

```
- (IBAction)clicked:(id)sender {
    textView.editable = YES;
    [textView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Optimally, you can make the textView always editable, or turn off editing after another button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

try use [textView becomeFirstResponder];

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers. @James has already posted this as an answer.

Comment: It's fine, I was just letting you know.